# Php Laravel include model in middle of the program

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, eloquent

I want to add models from one table called "modellist" in middle of the program.

```
foreach ($trans_infos as $key => $trans_info) {
                if($trans_info->heirarchy_type==1 || $trans_info->heirarchy_type==2){
                    $model=TransactionModules::where('id',$info->module_id)->first();
                    $model_name=$model->model; // here am getting model name form table
                    use  App\Models\.$model_name; //i used this function to include model on middle of program  
                    $model_name::find($info->transaction_id)->update(['status' => 7]);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but try:

```
foreach ($trans_infos as $key => $trans_info) {
            if($trans_info->heirarchy_type==1 || $trans_info->heirarchy_type==2){
                $model=TransactionModules::where('id',$info->module_id)->first();  
                ($model::class)::find($info->transaction_id)->update(['status' => 7]);
            }
        }
```

The class method returns the namespace with model name

I hope this works

Comment: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch error showing

Comment: i need to include model beofore using

Comment: Sorry it was worth a try. I am guessing that you are storing just the name of the model not the serialised model

Answer (score 0):

You can do this direct on eloquent.

no need to declare use first

> remember to use namespace as a string => "App\Models\\"

```
foreach ($trans_infos as $key => $trans_info) {
      if($trans_info->heirarchy_type==1 || $trans_info->heirarchy_type==2)
      {
          $model=TransactionModules::where('id',$info->module_id)->first();
          "App\Models\\".$model->model::find($info->transaction_id)
                                    ->update(['status' => 7]);
      }
 }
```